Operator exponential equality question: Does $X(\sigma) = Y\sigma$ imply $\exp(X)(\sigma) = \exp(Y)\sigma$?
See this question and other linked questions I am exploring on physics stack exchange. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/819663/ad-circ-exp-exp-circ-ad-and-ei-theta-2-hatn-cdot-sigma-sigma-e-i-t?noredirect=1&lq=1
I am working to prove
$$
U^{\dagger}(R)\sigma U(R) = e^{-i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot \sigma)}\sigma e^{-i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot J)} = e^{\theta (\hat{n}\cdot J)} \sigma = R\sigma
$$
where $\sigma$ is a vector of the Pauli matrices (basis elements of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$), $J$ is a vector of the matrix generators of rotations in 3D space (basis elements of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$), $\hat{n}$ is a unit 3-vector, and $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$.
I'm confident about my proof except for one step. I rely on
$$
\tag{A}
X(\sigma)=\text{ad}(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot\sigma))(\sigma) = \theta(\hat{n}\cdot J)\sigma = Y\sigma
$$
implies
$$
\tag{B}
\exp(X)(\sigma)=\exp(\text{ad}(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot\sigma)))(\sigma) = \exp(\theta(\hat{n}\cdot J))\sigma = \exp(Y) \sigma
$$

How exactly can this implication be justified? If I had proven
$$
X=\text{ad}(+i(\theta/2)(\hat{n}\cdot\sigma)) \stackrel{?}{=} \theta(\hat{n}\cdot J)=Y
$$
as an operator equality then I would understand why this would imply equality of the exponentials. But I haven't, I've only proven the action of the operator on the left on $\sigma$ equals the action of the operator on the right on $\sigma$.
Is the implication $X(\sigma) = Y\sigma \implies \exp(X)(\sigma) = \exp(Y)\sigma$ simply justified?
I worry because
$$
\exp(X)(\sigma) = \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{{X}^n}{n!}\right)(\sigma) = \sigma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{X^{n-1}}{n!} X(\sigma) = \sigma + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{X^{n-1}}{n!} Y\sigma
$$
This is good, but the next step would be
$$
= \sigma + Y\sigma + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{X^{n-2}}{n!} X(Y\sigma)
$$
I would then need $X(Y\sigma) \stackrel{?}{=} Y^2 \sigma$ but this is something I haven't yet proven. This would follow if $X(Y\sigma) \stackrel{?}{=} YX(\sigma) = Y^2\sigma$ but this I also haven't proven.

Perhaps I should focus on proving $X(Y\sigma) = YX(\sigma)$? Maybe this follow simply since $Y$ is just a matrix of scalars (in contrast to $X$ which is an operator)?


Perhaps I should focus on proving $X(Yσ)=YX(σ)$? Maybe this follow simply since $Y$
is just a matrix of scalars (in contrast to $X$ which is an operator)?

Indeed this is precisely the answer to the question. We prove this with index notation:
$$
(X(Y\sigma))_i = X((Y\sigma)_i) = X(Y_{ij}\sigma_j) = Y_{ij}X(\sigma_j) = Y_{ij}(X(\sigma))_j = (YX(\sigma))_i
$$
So indeed, it is generally true that $X(Y\sigma) = YX(\sigma)$.
This means that
$$
X(\sigma)=Y\sigma
$$
implies (by induction) that
$$
X^n(\sigma) = Y^n\sigma 
$$
so that
$$
\exp(X)(\sigma) = \exp(Y)\sigma
$$
